# Find previously selected option in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a drop down menu to keep its selected value when the user hits submit, but it fails due to errors on the form.

I have a while loop returning values from a database to build the options for the drop down, but how do I echo "selected" on the right option?

I have tried `if($district == $row["name"]) { echo "selected";}` as you see below, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT dist.name FROM districts AS dist JOIN int_bd AS ibd ON dist.id = ibd.districts_id WHERE banners_id = 6 GROUP BY dist.id ORDER BY dist.id ASC", $connection);
if (!result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="{$row["name"]}"'; if($district == $row["name"]) { echo "selected";} ; echo '>' . $row["name"] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

---

Sorry for the delay. None of the suggested answers worked for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: You cannot use single quotes & expect to get variables values, You should use double quotes.

Comment: $district is the variable where the selected option is stored.

Comment: Also, I suspect 'selected' will need a space somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT dist.name FROM districts AS dist JOIN int_bd AS ibd ON dist.id = ibd.districts_id WHERE banners_id = 6 GROUP BY dist.id ORDER BY dist.id ASC", $connection);
if (!result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$district = $_REQUEST['name']; // You need pass the value you have been submitted

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $selected ="";
     if(trim($district) == trim($row["name"])) {  $selected = "selected";} 

    echo '<option value="{$row["name"]}" '.$selected.' >' . $row["name"] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if($district == $row["name"])
{
echo "<option value='$district' selected>$district</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. This is what I did:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row["name"] . '"';
    if($row["name"] == $district) { echo 'selected';} ;
    echo '>' . $row["name"] . '</option>';
}
```

It seems to have been this line

```
echo '<option value="{$row["name"]}"';
```

that was causing the problem.